# Moving from console to JavaFX GUI

Tags: java, javafx

I decided to move my program from console-output based to JavaFX. First obstacle I encountered was that I am unable to display my old data structures.

From what I've read, JavaFX is following the MVC pattern, in that case, **does it mean that I have to rewrite all of my data structures (model) to JavaFX style?** (using properties). I have lots of data structures to handle time series prices data. **This would also mean that I have to rewrite all analysis functions to be compatible with new data structures.**

My original program loads an array list of time series data (each element is a custom object representing a datapoint, it contains a date field, level field (double)) and then performs analysis on it.

Comment: No, you can use any pretty much any data structure you like with JavaFX controls. The "wiring" to the controls is easier if you use the JavaFX Properties pattern, but there are basically always workarounds if you use other patterns. Note that if you do use the JavaFX properties pattern, your classes just look like regular Java Beans (with getXXX() and setXXX(...) methods) to other classes, so your other methods should continue to work just fine. Perhaps you can edit your question to provide a specific example of what you want to do?

Comment: The question will probably get closed, as it is too broad for StackOverflow as currently posited.  But ask again with a specific example that includes some minimal code and it will likely get answered.